# Linux shell script errors

Tags: c, linux, shell

I have to amke this script which combines every path from "PATH" with every argument of the script and to execute the "ls -l" command for each ... this is how I imagined it but i have some problems with it and don't know exactly what is the problem .... I get "Segmentation Faul(core dumped)" and if not then no matter how many arguments i give the output is the same so i think it's executing the command only for one of them but i'm not sure ... can anyone help me? ... sorry if my english is rough or the foreign language in the code ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main (int argc,char* argv[])
{
char* s=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(getenv("PATH")));
s=getenv("PATH");
if (argc==0) {printf("Nem irt be egyetlen parametert sem!");}
else
{
    char* seged=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(strtok(s,":"))+1));
    seged=strtok(NULL,":");
    strcat(seged,"/");
    int i=1;
    for (i=1;i<=argc;i++);
    {

        char* seged2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(1000));
        //char* seged2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(strtok(NULL,":"))+(strlen(argv[i]))+1));  if i use this line i get Segmentation Fault
        strcat(seged2,seged);
        strcat(seged2,argv[i]);
        int pid=fork();
        if (pid==0)
        {
            execl("/bin/ls","ls -l",seged2);
        }
        free(seged2);
    }
    while (strtok(NULL,":")!=NULL)
    {
        free(seged);            
        char* seged=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(strtok(NULL,":"))+1));
        seged=strtok(NULL,":");
        strcat(seged,"/");  
        for (i=1;i<argc;i++);
        {               
            char* seged2=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*(strlen(strtok(NULL,":"))+strlen(argv[i])+1));
            strcat(seged2,seged);
            strcat(seged2,argv[i]);
            pid_t pid=fork();
            if (pid==0)
            {
                execl("/bin/ls","ls -l",seged2);
            }
            free(seged2);
        }
    }   

}
```

}

Comment: use ddd debugger it will help you. on which line you are getting segmentation fault?

Comment: if you do not need it to be a C program, this will do fine (on sh/bash): `echo $PATH | sed 's/:/ /g' | xargs ls -l`

Comment: `sizeof(char)` is always 1 so it's not needed in your code, also don't typecast the return from `malloc()`, what line is the segfault occurring? I'm going to guess the memory is incorrectly allocated.

Comment: Why on earth are you doing this in C? It would be trivial 3-line script in shell.

Answer (score 1):

You must test the return value of `strtok()`. When there are no more tokens in your `PATH`, then `strtok()` returns `NULL` and `strlen(NULL)` gives your segmentation fault.

Please read `man strtok`.

I suggest you don't nest function calls this way, because there's always a chance, that you get unexpected return values.

Answer (score 1):

In Addition to what Olaf said:

You need to call the `execl` function with a separate string for each option you want to pass and terminate with the arguments with `NULL` like so:

```
execl("/bin/ls", "ls", "-l", seged2, 0);
```

See `man execl` for further reference.